# Writing a unix based operating system

Tags: c, unix, operating-system

So I was doing research on operating systems because I'm working on my own. I had heard about Unix a few years ago. I never really knew how much it influenced modern day computers until I saw [this photo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aUnix_history-simple.svg). Then I learned that parts of it were used in other operating systems such as OSX and the BSDs. 1. Where could I get the Unix source? 2. Where do I go the get my OS a unix certified? 3. Are there any legal things that I should keep in mind? 4. Is there anything that I should be mindful of when using the Unix source?

Comment: Linux and the Gnu tools (Linux/Gnu) are open source.  It's newer and better than actual Unix, so that would be the best place for sources.

Comment: Before doing it,  install linux on your PC  ( or use Virtual Box to run linux under windows ).  Or get FreeBSD,  and start having a play with it.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87011/how-to-easily-build-your-own-linux-distro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to stay away from the unix source code because there were so many company wars over it over the years that it became complicated ... 
in the other hand I strongly recommend you to check out the linux source code instead it's universely known to be 100% open source .
good luck with your OS

Answer (score 1):

If you're more interested in the roots of Unix rather than modern implementations (ie Linux), you might be interested in *Lion's Commentary on Unix 6th Edition with Source Code*, which [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lions%27_Commentary_on_UNIX_6th_Edition,_with_Source_Code) describes:

> Lions' Commentary on UNIX 6th Edition, with Source Code by John Lions
> (1976) contains the complete source code of the 6th Edition Unix
> kernel plus a commentary. It is commonly referred to as the Lions
> book. Despite its age, it is still considered an excellent commentary
> on simple but high quality code.
>
> For many years, the Lions Book was the only Unix kernel documentation
> available outside Bell Labs. Although the license of 6th Edition
> allowed classroom use of the source code, the license of 7th Edition
> specifically excluded such use, so the book spread through illegal
> copy machine reproductions (a kind of samizdat). It was commonly held
> to be the most copied book in computer science.

My old copy is printed and bound, but you can get the commentary online [here](http://www.lemis.com/grog/Documentation/Lions/index.php) in a variety of formats, and the source code can be found [here](http://www.tom-yam.or.jp/2238/src/). You can learn a lot about operating systems by reading the commentary, and learn a lot about programming by reading the excellent source.

Answer (score 1):

http://opengroup.org/austin/papers/single_unix_faq.html

> **Q8. What about UNIX Certification?**
>
> There is a mark, or brand, that is used to identify those products
>   that have been certified as conforming to the Single UNIX
>   Specification, initially UNIX 93, followed subsequently by UNIX 95,
>   UNIX 98 and now UNIX 03. Information on the UNIX certification program
>   which operates under The Open Group's Open Brand, can be found at
>   http://www.opengroup.org/certification/idx/unix.html
>
> The UNIX 03 Certification Guide is available at
>   http://www.opengroup.org/openbrand/docs/UNIX03_Certification_Guide.html.
>
> The Practical Guide to the Open Brand is available at
>   http://www.opengroup.org/openbrand/Certification_Guide/
>
> The register of Certified Products is available at
>   http://www.opengroup.org/openbrand/register/

As for source... You can find Linux kernel [in Linus Torvalds' GitHub pages](https://github.com/torvalds/linux). Not quite UNIX, but close. The rest of Linux consists of various GNU utilities, that you can find [on GNU pages](http://www.gnu.org/software).

But I dare say you are very very far from being able to implement your own brand of UN*X if you just heard about it a few years ago.

Answer (score 1):

*1. Where could I get the Unix source?* 
Linux/Gnu

*2. Where do I go the get my OS a unix certified?* 
I don't know and/or I don't understand the question.

*3. Are there any legal things that I should keep in mind?* 
Read the copyright and GPL info on Linux and Gnu.

*4. Is there anything that I should be mindful of when using the Unix source?*
See #3.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87011/how-to-easily-build-your-own-linux-distro